# Passenger Error on Hostmonster: "Could not initialize MySQL client library"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, hostmonster

I am trying to learn more about rails so I tried to follow this tutorial here on Hostmonster about how to set up a rails application:
https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/rails

I feel like I'm pretty close but now I'm getting the following error when I visit the public directory of my application:

> **Ruby (Rack) application could not be started**
>
> **Error message**: Could not initialize MySQL client library
>
> **Exception class**: RuntimeError
>
> **Application root**: /home1/stuartd1/public_html/dev/rails/newapp

The database information appears to be correct in database.yml and I tried a few random commands on the off chance one of them might fix it (bundle install, bundle update, rake, etc.). Any ideas?

Comment: Is the rails app version 4?

Comment: No, still unsolved. This is rails 4.2.0. I think it might have to weird issues with hostmonster specifically. The support there wasn't any help.

Comment: I'm in identical situation with bluehost. The tutorial you expose is identical to this other, and I suspect that the Linux machines configurations are the same. If you have any new please let me know. Bests.

Comment: hi, this already solve now??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on Bluehost. I solved it by using my own version of bundler and a change to my .htaccess file.

I had to install an updated bundler gem as my local user:

```
gem install bundler --user
```

And then use it in my .htaccess file

```
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home8/<myusername>/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/gems
```

After that I restarted passenger (e.g. touch tmp/restart.txt) and it all worked.

I'm using mysql2 gem -v 0.3.18